# Notification is showing every time I open my application

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I have an application in which i want to show notification to the user every day at 8:30 in the morning. everything is working fine. except one thing.
Notification is showing every time when I opens the application. I searched alot to this bug but I cant rectify this bug..

**This is the launcher class of my app.**

```
public class xyz extends Activity {




/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    Intent myIntent = new Intent(xyz.this , NotificationService.class);     
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(xyz.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);


        final ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
            //notify user you are online
             Thread Timer = new Thread(){               
                    public void run()
                    {   
                       try{                 

                           sleep(3000);

                       }catch(Exception e){

                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                     finally{


                    Intent openScreen = new Intent(xyz.this , Selection_Page.class);

                    startActivity(openScreen);

             }      

                    }       

                   };

                        Timer.start();
        } 
        else { // something in else} }}
```

**and this is my Notification service class.**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

private NotificationManager mManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    //super.onStart(intent, startId);
    // Getting Notification Service
    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(
                    this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    /*
     * When the user taps the notification we have to show the Home Screen
     * of our App, this job can be done with the help of the following
     * Intent.
     */
    Uri NOtification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), NOtification);
    r.play();


    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), Selection_Page.class);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.brand_icon,
            "See my app for you", System.currentTimeMillis());

    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
            "aaa", "See my app for you",
            pendingNotificationIntent);

    mManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

Please tell me where I am missing out something..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: i think in your service you should check to see if the time is 8:30

Comment: its there.. There is no error in this.. the notification is showing at 8:30.. but it is also showing whenever i opens my application

Comment: i think you are directly calling in your launcher activity. try to check timing in if condition if time is accurate then call your notification service

Comment: try commenting out your pendingintent and inside alarmManager.setRepeating() make new PendingIntent() for parameter

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed that you are setting alarm for `8:30` Today which is in the past since you are not changing the day value in the calender. So please try to change the day value to `today + 1` and try again. Following is the updated code with change in the `day` value:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(xyz.this , NotificationService.class);     
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(xyz.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calender.get(Calender.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);
```

Please test it let me know how it works...

Comment: In this way it will never trigger the alarm

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce a checkpoint here. Just compare the system time with the notification time that you want to trigger and if the system time is greater than the notification time, do nothing. else do notify.

Modify your code as below. It will work.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(xyz.this , NotificationService.class);     
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(xyz.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
long systemTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
if(systemTime <= calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);
}
else{
//do nothing
}
```